# Bluetooth not working in kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, bluetooth

I have installed Kubuntu 12.04 x64 bit tomorrow on my laptop. All seems to run fine but the Bluetooth is not! It says no adapter found. It worked great in ubuntu 11.10. How can I fix this? Let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the Bluetooth service running, and if you have BlueDevil properly installed with all its dependencies, including bluez. After that, check the status of your Bluetooth service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

After that, right click onto your Bluetooth icon, in the Plasma Desktop. You should see a message saying that your Bluetooth adaptor is off, with an option to turn it on. Do it.

Comment: Thanks i restarted my bluetooth adapter and it is working now....

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Then add these 2 lines at the end of the file:

```
usbserial
option
```

Save, close and restart. When you come back on, try your bluetooth again.

Comment: No luck! The Bluetooth indicator on my lappy show it is ON but kubuntu says no adapter found!

Comment: Do you have Atheros? If so, you might wanna update your firmware

Comment: I have a broadcom bluetooth adapter.